# Show that a function defined in terms of an infinite sum is strictly increasing in a neighborhood of the origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'd like to show that the function $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^{2+c}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-2\delta}{k} \frac{k+\delta}{B(\delta, \delta)} \exp\left\{ -\frac{(k+\delta)^2}{2z} \right\}$$ is strictly increasing in a neighborhood of the origin, where $c>0$, $\delta > 0$, $B(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the beta function given by $B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ for $x,y > 0$, and  $\binom{-2\delta}{k}:= (-1)^k \frac{\Gamma(k+2\delta)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(2\delta)}$.

Also, the neighborhood near the origin may depend on $c$, i.e., it may be of the form $(0,\eta_c)$ for some $\eta_c>0$. Any help would be appreciated.